# How can i user different pricing for music to sell using IAP in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, paypal

I'm new to iOS development.I'm working on a music app that has provision for registered users to sell music (from web) and buy music from app.Means, registered users can upload their music from web side and can put a specific price for that music for others to pay and download.

My doubt is that,when i searched for it,i saw as per Apple guidelines,we can't include any payment gateways like paypal to purchase a function or service within the app.Here i think,i cant use paypal for buying a music of 2$ from app without using IAP.

But there are only a few pricing options available in IAP in itunes.

Then my question is,Is there any way to buy  or download music with the price those music owners set for that particular music using IAP or using paypal or other gateways.

The price of music will be different as the one who uploaded it.how can buy those from iOS app.Please do help.thank you.

Comment: You will need to use IAP to let people purchase "credits" and then let them redeem those credits for the music

Comment: Can i use credit value of myown for a particular IAP transaction.i mean,if the amout to be paid is 2.99 USD,then after paying that money,can i award a credit of myown as a wallent for that.?@Paulw11

Comment: You could sell credits in whatever amount you want for whatever price you set. Apple will take 30% of that sale price

Comment: im sorry for asking clarification, u mean if user paid 45.99 usd,then he can buy using equivalent to that price,each time buying music of 2 or 3 usd's,that will be deducted from his account knw?@Paulw11

Comment: Let say you sold 100 credits for 45.99; that would give you about $0.32 per credit after apple's cut is deducted. So then you could price a $3 song at say 10 credits. You can't price songs in actual $ since the user cannot pay in $, only in credits

Comment: thanks paul.now i got it..You  are awesome